# Websphere Batch in existing Java EE application and parallelism in batch jobs

Tags: jakarta-ee, parallel-processing, websphere, batch-processing, zos

we're going to have a heterogeneous application which will be a standard OLTP application during the day and over night we are going to execute batch jobs. 
We will be using Websphere on the z series (with z/os).

My first question is should we deploy one application (including the websphere batch stuff)? Is that even possible?

Another problem we have is that we want to share our data access session beans between the OLTP and the batch processing in order to not repeat the code because they are both working on the same set of data. So can we easily integrate these session beans in our batch jobs?

I know that batch jobs and batch tasks can be designed and executed in a parallel mode. But is there even a more fine-grained approach to parallelize the tasks? Or is it standard that the batch task should always be executed in a sequential way?

Thank you very much

Comment: Just checking do you mean batch as in the language "@echo off & echo hello & pause"

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you mean. I was talking about a batch application using websphere batch (using websphere 8.5.5).

Comment: A .bat or a .cmd file.

Comment: There is no such file. It's going to be a batch application in Java with websphere. This means that batch jobs are described as xJCL files. Compare IBM red book about websphere 8.5, [link](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248022.html?Open) chapter 6

Comment: Then you don't need the batch-file tag as you are talking about a different batch.